# Generic view inheritance in Django

Tags: inheritance, multiple-inheritance, django-generic-views

The question is how to pass kwargs from URL to the parent class view?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<x>\d+)/(?P<y>\d+)/scout/$', 
        login_required(ScoutView.as_view()), name="scout"),
)
```

**views.py**

Look at first class **__*init*__** method.

```
class MapFieldActionView(TemplateView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """I NEED TO GET X AND Y HERE."""
        super(MapFieldActionView, self).__init__()
        x, y = kwargs['x'], kwargs['y']

class ScoutView(MapFieldActionView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScoutView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    template_name = "world/actions/scout.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access any kwargs you pass by the URL parameter to your class views using the self.kwargs dictionary. The dictionary will be available to the get_queryset() and get_context_data() methods.